# We have $10$ white and $20$ black balls in box. We take one by one out of it all together $13$ balls. Find the probability that last ball is white.

Tags: combinatorics

We have $10$ white and $20$ black balls in box. We take one by one (and we don't put it back in box) out of it all together $13$ balls.
Find the probability that last ball is white.

---

My try:

Enumerate the balls with numbers from $1$ to $30$ and arrange them all in a line.

Then we have $n= 30!$ and $m = 10\cdot 29!$ So $P= {1\over 3}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Each ball has a $\frac 13$ chance of being white, nothing special about being last.

Comment: Fun fact: the order of drawing the balls (or dealing out cards) isn't important (we basically permute a random permutation), so the probability of having the 13th ball be white is the same as having the first one white, therefore $1/3$

Comment: @lulu But if 1st was white then probability that 2nd is white is 9/29

Comment: So what?  That's a different problem.  Clearly, if you get more information the probability changes.  If the first ten draws are all white then the probability that the last is white is $0$, for example,

Comment: To use your example, if the first is black  then the second is white with probability $\frac {10}{29}$ so the total probability that the second is white is $\frac {10}{30}\times \frac 9{29}+\frac {20}{30}\times \frac {10}{29}=\frac 13$.

Comment: and .. $1/3$ is also the prob. to find a white ball among the $13$-th and $14$-th extracted, and so as well  among the $m$-th and $n$-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, applying counting:

- there are $30$ ways to extract the 1st ball
- there are $29$ ways to extract the 2nd ball
- there are $28$ ways to extract the 3rd ball
- ...
- there are $30-13+1=18$ ways to extract the **13th** ball

Altogether $30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot...\cdot18$

But we want the 13th ball to be white, so **we put $1$ white ball aside** and

- there are $29$ ways to extract the 1st ball
- there are $28$ ways to extract the 2nd ball
- there are $27$ ways to extract the 3rd ball
- ...
- there are $29-12+1=18$ ways to extract the **12th** ball

but **there are $10$ white balls** and each can be put aside, altogether $\color{red}{10}\cdot29\cdot28\cdot...\cdot18$.

As a result $$P=\frac{\color{red}{10}\cdot29\cdot28\cdot...\cdot18}{30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot...\cdot18}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

All the thirty balls have equal probability of being the thirteenth ball picked. So the answer is $\frac{10}{30}=\frac13$.